Invoice Icon in orders with VAT number in woocommerce order admin page
I would like to ask you if there is a posibility to add an Invoice Icon in orders with VAT number in woocommerce order admin page, please see an exaple here https://snipboard.io/r69lIQ.jpg?
For example, Is there a possibility to add a custom class to order list when invoice is requested. I am using a Checkout Field Editor (Checkout Manager) for WooCommerce plugin where I created the custom fields for billing_company and billing_vat, see screenshot here please https://snipboard.io/NfEs2R.jpg
Thank you in advance.
I tried use plugin's features but this is not possible with the Checkout Field Editor (Checkout Manager) for WooCommerce plugin

This should be a good starting point for you. Unfortunatly I don't know much about the Checkout Field Editor (Checkout Manager) for WooCommerce plugin. But this should work if you have custom meta fields.
First, you need to add a new column to the order table. You can do this by using the manage_edit-shop_order_columns filter.
Below code will add the new custom column with name VAT to the order table:
/*Add new custom column to admin order table */
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'set_custom_order_column' );
function set_custom_order_column($columns) {
    $columns['billing_vat'] = __( 'VAT', 'woocommerce' ); // You can change VAT to whaterver
    return $columns;
}

Next, you need to populate the new column with information from the VAT meta field. This can be done using manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column action hook. You also need to know the meta key for the field. You can find the meta key by inspecting the element in a browser. The id and name attributes from your image indicate billing_vat is the meta key used to store the VAT number.
Below code will populate the new column with the VAT information from the order, if it exists
/* Populate new column with VAT data from meta key billing_vat */
    add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_shop_order_column', 10, 2 );
    function custom_shop_order_column( $column, $post_id ) {
        if ( $column == 'billing_vat' ) {
          echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'billing_vat', true ) ); // change _billing_vat to your acutal meta key
        }   
    }

For more details, see the following post:

Metabox with multiple custom fields for WooCommerce admin order pages

You can also add an icon to the second function, depending on whether you want to use an image format (jpg, png, etc.) or an icon from an icon set (like FontAwesome).
The codes should be placed in the functions.php file of your active child theme.

Thank you Richard for the above solution. I already managed to add a billing_vat field to the order admin page as you may see here https://snipboard.io/wsIyMb.jpg. Now I need to add an INVOICE ICON to the Order list,  screenshot here https://snipboard.io/r69lIQ.jpg

@dorota is the icon already part of the theme (e.g. part of FontAwesome or another Icon set)? or do you have a custom icon image in the media library you would like to use?

I could use a custom icon.

Our theme uses https://heroicons.com/ library
